# What if you eat meat with cancer?

Tags: cancer, food-safety

I saw a picture on Facebook about butcher's cutting out cancer when processing meat.

If consumed, would it be dangerous to us? Can we get sick? I'm assuming the body's immune system would recognize the cells as foreign since its animal meat, but would it do anything?

Also, I have not looked into whether this picture had any truth to it. But my question still stands if it is false.

[image: Picture mentions]

Comment: Cancer is not contagious in any way. Eating cancer-containing meat will not result in your developing cancer.

Comment: What Bill said. Probably wouldn't taste so great and definitely wouldn't look so great, but harmless to eat. I could see it becoming a weird gourmet item.

Comment: Although cancer is theoretically non-contagious, and theoretically we **shouldn't** be adversely affected, seeing as we don't know all causes of cancer, or do we?, this question is to my mind valid.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Has someone suggested otherwise?

Comment: [related](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/78792/can-a-cancerous-cell-from-outside-cause-cancer-in-a-healthy-person/78800#78800)